# What are stones and bottles for in Silent Hill: Downpour?

Tags: silent-hill-downpour

In Silent Hill: Downpour, there are plenty of stones and bottles around. I don't quite prefer using them as I find other tools like axe, wrench, etc. more powerful.

So, is there something special about the stones and bottles in the game? Why should I use them? I know they can be thrown upon creatures and birds, but is that just it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's pretty much all they're for, as far as I can tell so far.  Since pretty much everything in this game is breakable, I can imagine you might be in a situation where you don't have access to a more traditional weapon and whacking an enemy in the face with a bottle is better than trying to use your fists, at least...